# Trying to write DataFrame to csv file

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

i am trying to write my DataFrame to CSV file. I tried this

```
df.write.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").option("header", true)
  .option("codec", "org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.GzipCodec").save("myFile.csv")
```

but it gives me the error :

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: CSV data source does not support array<struct<columnName:columntype...
```

if i however show the DataFrame on the console, it prints fine. How can i write to a csv or even a text file would do.

Thanks!!

**EDIT**

I didn't need to write everything out. I selected out the rows needed and got it working thanks for the help though!

Comment: Can you provide the schema of DataFrame (`df.schema`) ?

Answer (score 1):

You dataframe has a complex column (an Array of structs it seems like). With csv you can only have simple column types like String, Int, Date, etc, but no arrays or structs.

Comment: This answer does not contain a solution.